# Symfony Assert Min Value

Tags: symfony, assert

I have a video entity that only contains a video from YouTube. To do this, I have to add a constraint in the entity with an assert, I tried "Range" with minimum: https://youtube.com/watch?v= and by specifying the string group. It’s no working! Help me! Here is the code of the entity:

```
    /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Range(
 *  min = "https://youtube.com/watch?v=",
 *  groups = {"string"}"
 * )
 */
private $video;
```

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html Regex is a more appropriate check. Range is for Numbers and Dates

Answer (score 0):

You should try to solve this task with a custom validation constraint. It allows your code to assert that a request parameter contains **https://youtube.com/watch?v=** or even to check that video url is a valid video (with request to a Youtube API with a help of Guzzle client or Youtube API library). More info see in the official Symfony docs. https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html